# CompletableFuture with void methods

Tags: java, completable-future

I'm looking to run two methods `a()` and `b()` that take in no arguments and return nothing (i.e. void methods) asynchronously such that they are returned in any order concurrently.

However, a third method `c()` should only run after either of the other above methods complete.

I believe I am supposed to create two CompletableFuture objects (cf1 for `a()` and cf2 `b()`) and then use `CompletableFuture.anyOf(cf1, cf2).join()` to block the code for `c()`.

However, I am not sure how to create the cf1 and cf2 CompletableFuture objects. I understand the methods `a()` and `b()` are essentially like Runnable's `run` method but I do not want to change the way they are implemented. Which of CompletableFuture's methods should I call in order to create this CompletableFuture objects for the two methods?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do something like this to wait until either of method `a()` or `b()` is completed and then once one of them is completed, you run method `c()`.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> cf1 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> a());
CompletableFuture<Void> cf2 = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> b());
CompletableFuture<Void> cf3 = CompletableFuture.anyOf(cf1, cf2).thenRunAsync(() -> c());
```

Comment: This works but I never considered using runAsync cause I believed that that was only for Runnable types. Could you explain why this works?

A sample of method `a()` implementation is shown below:
`public static void a() { System.out.println("Hello");  }`

Comment: Well yes runAsync is for Runnable types and your problem had 3 methods with void types, so basically I am just creating Runnable when I do () -> someMethod(). (If that's what you were confused about)

Comment: Basically, you are creating 2 CompleteableFutures with no return types i.e. side effect method. Then we create a 3rd CompleteableFuture which   waits for anyOf the two futures to complete and thenRuns the final method c() asynchronously.

Comment: Okay got it! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can directly use `runAfterEither` as this

```
    CompletableFuture<Void> a = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        Util.delay(new Random().nextInt(1000));
        System.out.println("Hello ");
    });

    a = a.runAfterEither(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        Util.delay(new Random().nextInt(1000));
        System.out.println("Hi ");
    }), () -> {
        System.out.println("world"); // your c();
    });

    a.join();
```